# Rules does not have any action for publish selected content

Tags: 7, nodes, rules, actions

In `admin/content` page we have some update options. I want to execute a Php code only when I use `publish selected content` or `unpublished selected content` on that page.

This rules should be fired JUST when I `publish/unpublished selected content`

Comment: What do you want to happen if some selected content gets published (or unpublished) without using "admin/content" (eg simply using a node edit form to do so)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use drupal's `hook_form_alter()` for firing your PHP code. Check below example:

```
function contr_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'node_admin_content'){
    $form['admin']['options']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'CUSTOM_SUBMIT_HANDLER';
  }
}
```

and then you can write your PHP code in CUSTOM_SUBMIT_HANDLER function as below:

```
function CUSTOM_SUBMIT_HANDLER($form, $form_state){
  if($form_state['values']['operation'] == 'publish'){
    // Do your stuff when PUBLISH here.
  }elseif ($form_state['values']['operation'] == 'unpublish') {
    // Do your stuff when UNPUBLISH here.    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to alter the action performed on publish or unpublish of the node.

Try using hook_action_info_alter to alter the existing actions.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_action_info_alter/7.x